# Thermal printing via code: max length gets truncated

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing

I am printing receipts over a thermal printer via code. The length of the receipt is always truncated to pretty much exactly 30cm. The width of the RectangleF is set to 300 (which corresponds to roughly 8cm), so he only prints about 1200 units worth of height. I can reduce the height below 1200, which further truncates the length of the receipt below 30cm, but he doesn't print more than 30cm. When printing via Notepad or Word, I can print meters without end in one go.

```
private void print(string printString)
{
    PCPrint printer = new PCPrint();

    printer.TextToPrint = printString;
    printer.Print();
}
public class PCPrint : System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument
{
    string printText;
    RectangleF printArea = new RectangleF(0, 0, 300, 10000);
    public string TextToPrint
    {
        get { return printText; }
        set { printText = value; }
    }
    protected override void OnPrintPage(PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(printText, new Font("Verdana", 8), Brushes.Black, printArea);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

from
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

I read that:
Typically, you create an instance of the PrintDocument class, set properties such as the DocumentName and PrinterSettings, and call the Print method to start the printing process. Handle the PrintPage event where you specify the output to print, by using the GraphicsGraphics property of the PrintPageEventArgs.

Maybe inspect the PrinterSettings for values that are limiting your page size.